# How to create feed/scroll page for android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build this social media type app for android, but I've been having trouble with building a feed page like the one facebook or reddit has where you can post things and have people either respond of like it can anybody suggest any tutorials or tell what I can use to build this would greatly appreciate it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use firbase database for this type of project.

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


private void writeNewPost(String postId, String post, String postOwner) {
    Post post = new Post(post, postId, postOwner);

    mDatabase.child("posts").child(postId).setValue(post);
}
```

Check this post this will help you

[SocialMedia app like and comments implements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094624/socialmedia-app-like-and-comments-implements/49094888#49094888)

Check firebase documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write